# Can 32-bit (void *) generic (32-bit OS) be used for storing uint64_t data?

Tags: c, linux

Is using a void pointer a portable approach for generic data types in C (assuming I do NOT want to use a preprocessor macro or a union type)? The reason this question arises is because let's say I wanted to store uint64_t data in a void pointer in a 32-bit Linux distro (=> sizeof(void *) = 4 bytes), is it safe to typecast uint64_t to (void *) for passing to functions and then typecasting it back to uint64_t later to retrieve the data?

Comment: No, it’s not safe.  You’ll only have 32 of the 64 bits from the original number.  Rethink what you’re trying to do.

Comment: If `sizeof(void*)` is 4 bytes aka 32 bits, it can't store 64 bits of information.

Comment: Bjarne Stroustrup: “C makes it easy to shoot yourself in the foot..." :)

Comment: @InnocentBystander and in C++ [*you accidentally create a dozen instances of yourself and shoot them all in the foot. Providing emergency medical assistance is impossible since you can't tell which are bitwise copies and which are just pointing at others and saying, "That's me, over there."*](http://www.toodarkpark.org/computers/humor/shoot-self-in-foot.html)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala LMAO that's awesome :)

Comment: @InnocentBystander Totally unrelated, but cool note: Bjarne Stroustrup was one of my dad's first professors at college.

Comment: You might be confusing a pointer *pointing* to data with a pointer *storing* data. A `void` pointer can point to data of any type and size, that's why it's called a generic pointer. But it can store only as many bits as it has.

Comment: Not sure it's what you're asking, but you obviously can't store 64 bits of of data in a 32-bit type.  See the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Answer (score 1):

The common way to store `uint64_t` data "in a" `void *`, or to store *any other kind of data* "in a pointer to void" is to make that pointer to *point to an object of type `uint64_t` (or that any other desired type)*, and let that object hold the value.

It might seem *too* obvious for some but it comes up at least weekly on Stack Overflow especially with `pthread_create` and `pthread_join` - with those APIs you're meant to have that pointer to *point* to the desired data that you might need in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

A `void*` is for storing the `address` that holds any kind of sized type. It is not meant for storing integer values which do not symbolize an address of memory.

If you want to store multiple differently sized types in a single type without a pointer, consider using an enum compound type. This type would use two 32 bit integers to work on a 32bit system.

```
enum 32_or_64_int_t {
      UINT32_TYPE,
      UINT64_TYPE
};

struct 64_int_t {
    uint32_t value[2];
    enum 32_or_64_int_t type;
};
```

You would still need to implement 64bit arithmetic and other operations using this approach if you wanted to do more then just storage it.